Access violation reading with skip list
I am doing Stroustrup's PPP2 chapter 18 exercise 11: "Research and implement a skip list."
This code gives the exception: Exception thrown at 0x00007FF61A3E656F in Skip List.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000020.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

// Error on lines 91 & 95: read-access violation: could be related to nullptr in constructors
// Only the first half is relevant to the exception
// 
const int maxLevel = 16;

class Node {
public:
    std::vector<Node*> next; // vector to hold next nodes at each level
    int value;

    Node(int value, int level) : value(value), next(level+1, nullptr) {}; // each node knows its position in the hierarchy, next vector is initialized to have level+1 elements, all set to 0

    void addNext(Node* node, int level) // add space for upcoming elements if next is not big enough
    {
        if (level >= next.size())
        {
            next.resize(level + 1, 0); 
        }
        next[level] = node;
    }

    ~Node() // destructor
    {
        for (auto& n : next)
        {
            delete n;
        }
    }
};

class skipList {
    int level;
    Node* head; // starting point of the skipList
    double P; // fraction/percentage of promotion
public:
    skipList() : level(1), head(), P(0.5) {}; // Default 
    skipList(int level, Node* head, double P) : level(level), head(head), P(P) // Constructor with parameters 
    {
        try {
            if (head == nullptr)
            {
                std::runtime_error("head can't be nullptr");
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            std::cerr << "Unkown Exception!" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    // main functions
    void insert(int value);
    void remove(int value);
    void search(int value);
    void display();

    // helper functions
    int randomNumber();
};

int skipList::randomNumber()  
{
    float r = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    int lvl = 0;
    while (r < P && lvl < maxLevel)
    {
        lvl++;
        r = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }
    return lvl;
}

void skipList::insert(int value)
// Insert into base level
// Promote the inserted element depending on a probability
// Repeat until highest level or no promotion possible
try {
    //    Key of next node is less than key to be inserted then we keep on moving forward on the same level
    //    Key of next node is greater than the key to be inserted then we store the pointer to current node i at update[i] and move one level down and continue our search.
    Node* newNode = new Node(value, 0);
    Node** current = &head;

    for (int i = level; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (*current == nullptr) break;
        while ((*current)->value < value && *current != nullptr)
        {
            current = &(*current)->next[i]; // increment current, & returns address of pointer to next
        }
        if (*current != nullptr || (*current)->value > value) 
            // reached point of insertion or end of level
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            newNode->addNext(*current, i);
            *current = newNode;
        }
    }

    int rlvl = randomNumber(); // generate random level for node
    // If level is increasing
    if (rlvl <= maxLevel && rlvl != level)
    {
        //Add new nodes at the top level
        for (int i = level; i < rlvl; ++i)
        {
            newNode->addNext(newNode, i); 
        }
        // Update the head pointer
        head = newNode;
        level = rlvl; 
    }
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
catch (...)
{
    std::cerr << "Unkown Exception!\n";
}

void skipList::display()
// Function to display the skipList
{
    std::cout << "\n\n\t---skipList---\n\n";
    for (int i = level; i >= 0; i--) // start at top level, go down
    {
        Node* temp = head;
        while (temp != nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << temp->value << " ";
            temp = temp->next[i];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    // seed randnum generator
    srand((unsigned)time(0));

    // insert() test
    Node node(1, 1);
    skipList SkipList(1, &node, 0.5);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++)
    {
        SkipList.insert(i); 
    }
    SkipList.display();   
}

After removing certain pieces of the code, it seems like the issue is me dereferencing a nullptr in the nested while loop and if statement in skipList::insert(): (*current)->value >/< value. When I get rid of this piece of code, it runs but outputs nothing. I have added a cout before this if statemment: if (*current == nullptr) break;, and it outputs a bunch of 0's, which I assume means its a nullptr. I've tried changing around my constructors but nothing I do seems to fix it.
Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

OT: Throwing an exception then immediately catching it makes no sense.

As for the crash, "reading location 0x0000000000000020" is indicating that you're using a null pointer (with an offset of 32 bytes from it).

And a general tip, don't write many lines all at once without testing. Start with an empty main function. Build with extra warnings enabled, and treated as errors. When the code builds cleanly, test it. Then add a very small bit of code, perhaps even just one or two lines. This way, when you get a problem (like a crash) it's really easy to isolate it into a proper [mre] for debugging. And for testing, use hard-coded and known values as "input", to make it deterministic.

Think about the order of evaluation here and what happens when *current is nullptr: while ((*current)->value < value && *current != nullptr)

Similar problem with if (*current != nullptr || (*current)->value > value). I stop here, because this means you need to run your code with a debugger, and really perform debugging tasks.
